# The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of IncomingMessage in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

> I am new to NodeJs, I Create custom server setup but when I Run the
> server setup It throw an error of this type

```
PS E:\MyNodeProjedt\myDream> node Server.js
node:internal/validators:120
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of IncomingMessage
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:120:11)
    at Url.parse (node:url:169:3)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (node:url:156:13)
    at Server.<anonymous> (E:\MyNodeProjedt\myDream\Server.js:15:21)
    at Server.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:951:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

> Server.js

```
const http  = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const mimeTypes = {
    "html" : "text/html",
    "jpeg" : "text/jpeg",
    "jpg"  : "text/jpg",
    "png"  : "text/png",
    "js"  : "text/javaScript",
    "css"  : "text/css"
};
http.createServer(function(req,res){
     var  uri = url.parse(req,url).pathname;
    let fileName = path.join(process.cwd(),unescape(url));
    Console.console.log('Loading'+uri);
    let stats;
    try {
        stats = fs.lstatSync(fileName);
    } catch (error) {
        res.writeHead(404,{'Content-type':'text/plain'});
        res.write('404 Not Found\n');
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    if(stats.isFile){
        let mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(fileName).split(".").reverse()[0]];
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':MimeType});

        let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }else if(stats.isDirectory()){
        res.writeHead(302,{
            'location' : 'index.html'
        });
        res.end();
    }else{
        res.writeHead(500,{'Content-type':'text/plain'});
        res.write('500 Internal error\n');
        res.end();
    }
    
}).listen(3000);
```

> This is the my custom setup of server ,but it is not working ,How to
> handle this type of issue
> I take reference from internet ,but I am not able to find my mistake
> how can I setup my own server setup. which is the better way to define
> custom server setup

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from this line:

```
var  uri = url.parse(req,url).pathname;
```

It needs to be:

```
var  uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

The function `url.parse()` expects a string (see in the error: `"The "url" argument must be of type string"`), but instead it's getting an object (`req`). Changing it to `req.url` gets you the `url` prop on the `req` object.